# Escaping Laravel Blade @include Contents for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I am working with a dynamic form in Laravel.

I've abstracted the reusable form bits to an `@include` with some JS logic to handle incrementing form `name=[]` id's based on the id passed when the user adds another widget.

When the user clicks to add another widget to the form, I'd like to simply call the include with an incremented counter - **that's all sorted** - however, the output of the `@include` is not friendly for JavaScript what-so-ever.

Searching around, I've found the following:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/blade-content-escaping

...and it seems that extending blade to create a custom directive may be the answer:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#extending-blade

My question is, will I be able to wrap an `@include` with a custom directive, say `@js(@include())` - or - is this not the way to go at all?

This is the only instance of this structure in my entire project so I'm not using VUE.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I tried throwing together a directive

`Blade::directive('js', function ($expression) {
    return str_replace(array('  ', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $expression);
});`

Issue is the `@include` doesn't evaluate... Rabbit hole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with a custom blade directive:

#### AppServiceProvider

`Blade::directive('js', function ($expression) {
    return "<?php echo trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', \$__env->make({$expression}))); ?>";
});`

#### JS in Blade

`var newWidget = '@js("components.widgets", ["widgetId" => 'widgetId'])';
newWidget = newWidget.replace(/widgetId/g,widgetId);`

I'm using the replace to insert the incrementing widgetId.

Thanks for everyones' input.

Answer (score 1):

You may not assign directly a Blade template output to a JavaScript variable, but you can make the Blade output invisible (`display: none`) and refer to it with Javascript.

I.E. instead of:

```
var JsElement = @include('blade.template', $data)
```

You can do this in your blade page:

```
<div id="template-element" style="display: none">
    @include('blade.template', $data)
</div>
```

and then refer and clone it through javascript:

```
var JsElement = document.getElementById('template-element');
var clonedElement = JsElement.cloneNode()
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did it before:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>{{ Form::input('text', 'first_name[]', null) }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
{{ Form::button('add', ['id' => 'add']) }}

<script>
 $('#add').click(function() {    
    var newrow = $('#myTable tr:last').html();    
    $('#myTable tr').last().after('<tr>' + newrow + '</tr>');
  });
</script>
```

this is just a rough sample, but should be enough to get you started.

Comment: That doesn't address my question which is how to properly escape the the contents of an @include in blade for assignment to a javascript variable. The "dynamic" functionality of add/remove, etc is all set. Appreciate the reply though.

Comment: if you need to use the content of a blade file, then you need to use an ajax call for that

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>{{ Form::input('text', 'first_name[]', null) }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
{{ Form::button('add', ['id' => 'add']) }}

$('#add').click(function() {    
    $.ajax({
    url:"/mylink",
    method:"GET",
    success:function(data){
       $('#myTable tr').last().after('<tr>' + data + '</tr>');      
    }
  });
});
```

On your controller

```
public function myMethod()
{
   $data = view('myviewfile')->render();
   return response()->json(['html'=>$data]);
}
```

On you route:

```
Route::get('/mylink', 'MyController@myMethod')->name('myRouteName');
```